# Sum only required array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to Sum all elements of array, up to the selected value of input (first four elements in this example):

HTML:

```
<input id="VAL" value="4" />

<button onclick="SUM()">BUTTON</button>

SUM: <span id="bubu"></span>
```

JS:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function getSum(x,y) {return x+y;}

function SUM() { 
    document.getElementById("bubu").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
}
```

Now the sum of all elements work correctly. But how can I add a loop, to get only required sum?

[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o2e389fp/)

Comment: by required you mean elements that satisfy a condition ?

Comment: you need to be more clear, what is required sum? is it the number for elements from the array you want to sum, or soething else.

Comment: @Vaibhav, thanks, edited. I mean the numer of elements.

Comment: i finally understood the question, he wants to sum only the first n values of the array, and n = input number.

Comment: add first n elements of an array is what you need to search on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for loop`, it's pretty simple.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let upTo = 4;

var res = 0;

for(let i = 0; i<upTo; i++){
     res += numbers[i];
}

console.log(res)
```

Using `reduce()`

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let upTo = 4;

var res = numbers.reduce((a,e,i)=>(i<upTo)?a+e:a+0)

console.log(res)
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fsbhoe45/

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two ways:

1. <s>[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)</s> [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) first, removing the values you don't want to sum up *(edited because of the OP's comment "I mean the numer of elements")*, or
2. In your [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) callback, don't add `y` if it's not one of the values you want to include (by checking the index you receive as the third argument to the callback)

Comment: This answer encourages improving fishing skills. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use the reduce index parameter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

window.SUM = function() { 
    var numberOfElements = document.getElementById("VAL").value;
    document.getElementById("bubu").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(function(x, y, i){
        if(i <= numberOfElements-1) {
        return x+y;
      } else {
        return x;
      }
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9vrLsnm/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using `reduce` alone if you supplied a `limit` to handler that indicates the index up to which you need the sum for. For e.g. if you need sum up to 4 elements then limit is 3.

```
function onClickHandler(limit) {
    return numbers.reduce(function (acc, val, index) {
        return index < limit ? acc : acc + val
    }, 0)
}
```

Hope this helps.